# Add a column to select for order_by in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, select, ruby-on-rails-5, arel, pg-query

I have a complicated db query that selects schools based on real estate listing attributes, performance statistics for the schools, and the distance of each listing to public transit. Users create a `Search` object, and a method `find_schools` in the `search.rb` has this query:

```
         School.where(id: school_ids).narrow_schools_for_search(self,prop_type,status,year).joins(listings: 
         :cta_listings).joins(:performance_stats).where("cta_listings.distance <= ?", 
         self.cta_distance).where.not(performance_stats: {"#{sort_column.to_sym}" => 
         nil}).distinct.limit(30).order("performance_stats.#{sort_column} DESC")

School.rb
scope :narrow_schools_for_search, ->(search,prop_type,status,year) {joins(:listings).joins(:performance_stats)
     .where("listings.beds >= ?",search.beds).where("listings.price <= ?",search.max_price)
     .where("listings.price >= ?",search.min_price).where(listings: {prop_type: prop_type, status: status})
     .where(performance_stats: {year: year}).distinct}
  
  has_many :performance_stats, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :assignments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :listings, through: :assignments

Listing.rb
has_many :assignments, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :schools, through: :assignments
    has_many :cta_listings, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :cta_stations, through: :cta_listings
    has_many :metra_listings, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :metra_stations, through: :metra_listings

PerformanceStat.rb
belongs_to :school
```

I need the Schools ordered by an attribute in the associated table PerformanceStats, which is a user defined attribute `sort_column`. The query works in development env (sqlite3), but fails on the staging app (PG) with this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
```

I need to add a select statement that includes the column name by which I am sorting schools.

The advice on other posts [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42846286/pginvalidcolumnreference-error-for-select-distinct-order-by-expressions-mus) is to do something like:

```
Widget.select('"widgets".*, "widget_steps.name"')
```

So, for my case, I tried this:

```
sort_for_select = "performance_stats.#{sort_column}"

    School.select('"schools".*, "#{sort_for_select"').where(id: school_ids).narrow_schools_for_search(self,prop_type,status,year).joins(listings: 
                 :cta_listings).joins(:performance_stats).where("cta_listings.distance <= ?", 
                 self.cta_distance).where.not(performance_stats: {sort_column.to_sym => 
                 nil}).distinct.limit(30).order("performance_stats.#{sort_column} DESC")
```

But my editor is indicating I'm not actually escaping to to ruby. I tried it anyway, and sure enough, it fails with

```
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "#{sort_for_select}" does not exist.
```

Then I tried hard coding the `sort_column`:

```
School.select('"schools".*, "performance_stats.grall_adjpicalc"').where(id: school_ids).narrow_schools_for_search(self,prop_type,status,year).joins(listings: 
                     :cta_listings).joins(:performance_stats).where("cta_listings.distance <= ?", 
                     self.cta_distance).where.not(performance_stats: {grall_adjpicalc:
                     nil}).distinct.limit(30).order("performance_stats.grall_adjpicalc DESC")
```

This works in dev environment, but if fails on the staging app with this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "performance_stats.grall_adjpicalc" does not exist
```

So at this point I have to deploy every time to test new ideas. I know PG in development would be ideal, but I lost an entire week trying to change over and couldn't get it to work. ended up losing everything and had to reseed from scratch.

I have 3 questions:

1. What am I doing wrong with the Select statement?
2. Is there another fast way to do this that avoids this issue? I was thinking instead of Distinct, perhaps I could go with uniq, converting to an array then sort the array accordingly.
3. How can I get the variable `sort_column` into the select statement?

Any thoughts or suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: String interpolation (like `"text #{variable} text"`) only works inside double quotes. So if `foo = "bar"` then `"#{foo}" == "bar"` but `'#{foo}' != "bar" && '#{foo}' == "\#\{foo\}"`. I don't know what the fix is for the select though, as SQL isn't my specialty

Comment: However, the PG error `column "performance_stats.grall_adjpicalc" does not exist` is pretty self explanatory -- that column does not exist, possibly due to not having run migrations that were required in the production environment.

Comment: grall_adjpicalc definitely exists, and it works in the dev environment. Only in production does it fail with the statement that column doesn't exist. I'm thinking postgres wants a different syntax since I'm joining :performance_stats with :schools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: the working code in my original answer was slow, often ending up in timeouts on Heroku.  I ended up with a query that operates 3x faster using arel_tables.  The working code looks like this (`self` is an `@search` object). I'm not a professional coder, so without a doubt this could perform even faster, and I welcome any suggestions to speed up performance. It still takes 5-8 seconds depending on the query. But at least I'm not getting timed out anymore.

```
  school = School.arel_table
  pstat = PerformanceStat.arel_table
  schools = school.project(Arel.star).join(pstat).on(pstat[:school_id].eq(school[:id]).and(
          school[:area_id].in(self.area_ids).and(
              pstat[:year].eq(year)
            )
          )
        )
   query = schools.to_sql
   school_ids = School.find_by_sql(query).pluck(:id)
```

This gives me an array of possible school ids, now I need to find the listings in these schools that match the other search parameters, including max distance to public transit if selected. Schools and listings are joined via an Assignment model.

```
        listing = Listing.arel_table
        assignment = Assignment.arel_table
         if self.cta || self.metra
           cta_listing = CtaListing.arel_table
           metra_listing = MetraListing.arel_table
           
           listing_assign = listing.join(assignment).on(assignment[:listing_id].eq(listing[:id])).join(cta_listing, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin).on(cta_listing[:listing_id].eq(listing[:id])).join(metra_listing, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin).on(metra_listing[:listing_id].eq(listing[:id]))
           
           selected_listings = listing_assign.project(assignment[:school_id], listing[:id]).where(
           assignment[:school_id].in(school_ids).and(
           cta_listing[:distance].lteq(self.cta_distance).or(
           metra_listing[:distance].lteq(self.metra_distance))).and(
           listing[:prop_type].in(prop_type).and(
           listing[:status].in(status).and(
           listing[:beds].gteq(self.beds).and(
           listing[:active].eq(true).and(
           listing[:price].lteq(self.max_price).and(
           listing[:price].gteq(self.min_price))))))))
         else
           listing_assign = listing.join(assignment).on(assignment[:listing_id].eq(listing[:id]))

           selected_listings = listing_assign.project(assignment[:school_id], listing[:id]).where(
           assignment[:school_id].in(school_ids).and(
           listing[:prop_type].in(prop_type).and(
           listing[:status].in(status).and(
           listing[:beds].gteq(self.beds).and(
           listing[:active].eq(true).and(
           listing[:price].lteq(self.max_price).and(
           listing[:price].gteq(self.min_price))))))))

         end

       q = selected_listings.to_sql
       listings = Listing.find_by_sql(q)
```

Now I have an AR Relation of all the listings that match the search. I can't limit to 30 schools before this point, because I'm not sure if a school will have any listings that match the requirements. Every school must have at lease one listing. I need to return the top 30 schools and their listings, so first I create an array of arrays with each listings id and the corresponding school_id.

```
       listings_array = listings.map{|x| [x.school_id,x.id]}
```

Then I convert this array of arrays into a hash grouping by school_id:

```
       listings_hash = listings_array.group_by{|school_id| school_id.shift}.transform_values do |values|
   values.flatten.uniq
 end
```

Now I can sort these schools by the selected column and pick the top 30.

```
 if sort_column.nil?
   sort_column = "grall_adjpicalc"
 end

 schools = School.where(id: listings_hash.keys).includes(:performance_stats).where(performance_stats: 
 {year: year}).order("performance_stats.#{sort_column} desc").limit(30)
```

Now I have our top 30 schools and can return an array of arrays with each school and its corresponding listing_ids.

```
 schools_array = schools.map{|school| [school,listings_hash[school.id]]}
 return schools_array
```

This is much longer that the previous answer, but at least 3x faster. Can you find a way to make this significantly faster?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up dropping the `distinct` and `order` in favor of `merge` and `uniq`. The working code looks like this, but it is an array of objects instead of an ActiveRecord Relation:

```
School.where(id: school_ids).narrow_schools_for_search(self,prop_type,status,year).joins(listings: 
     :cta_listings).joins(:performance_stats).where("cta_listings.distance <= ?", 
     self.cta_distance).where.not(performance_stats: {"#{sort_column.to_sym}" => 
     nil}).merge(PerformanceStat.order("#{sort_column.to_sym}" => :desc)).uniq[0..29]
```